# Liferay6.2 Theme building using Gradle/Gulp script

Tags: gradle, gulp, liferay-6, liferay-theme

Can any help me on how to write the automated  gradle/gulp script for Liferay6.2 theme building.

I would like execute the following goals to build the .war file and i am using portal-web-6.2.10.13.war.

-theme-merge

-build-css

-build-thumbnail

Configuration:
ParentTheme: _styled
ParentThemeType: vm

I can able to successfully generate the themes war by using Maven but unable to succeed using gradle build. Appreciate your help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Development of themes of appearance themes 6.2 and 7 - Liferay**

Dependencies

We work on Windows so the explanations will be done for the work under this platform, although we believe that it is easily extrapolated to those who work under Linux or Mac.

We will need to have installed the following:

**Nodejs**

**Python 2.7.10** (Windows only)

**Visual Studio** (Windows only) When installing it, we only need to check the following box, the rest we can unmark them all: Custom> Programming ...> ***Visual C ++*** (the installation process is long)
Once all the dependencies are installed, we will proceed with the following step:

***Yeoman, Gulp and Bower***

Yeoman, Gulp and Bower are the three tools on which we will base ourselves to create and compile our new appearance themes. We must bear in mind that we are facing an Alpha version of Liferay, so we can find problems that will be fixed over time, but it is important to get used to new work methodologies that will make our lives easier.

We summarize:

Yeoman. They are defined as a "web scaffolding for modern applications". We can say that it is an assistant that helps us create our web projects.
Gulp will be our nodejs tool to compile our appearance themes.
Bower will be our tool for managing dependencies
Let's do it! First of all let's proceed to install Yeoman, Gulp and Bower. We place ourselves on the Windows console and type the following command:

```
npm install -g yo gulp bower
```

Now it's time to install the liferay theme generator. For this, in the same command line we will write the following:

```
npm install -g generator-liferay-theme
```

Creating appearance themes
For the creation of appearance theme we will use Yeoman. In the command line, on the directory that we want to create the theme, we type:

```
yo liferay-theme
```

You can mess around with the subject to analyze some news about the method of work with ant or maven. For example now in the package.json file is where the parent theme is defined, if we have decided to use velocity or freemarker or the name of the theme. In liferay-theme.json the paths of the theme and the tomcat will be defined, for example. The rest will work as in previous versions. Inside the folder src we will be placing our folders css, js, templates, images ... with their corresponding files.

Now we will only have to compile our theme of appearance. To do this we place ourselves on the theme directory from the console and type the following:

```
gulp build or gulp deploy
```

The first will compile our theme and generate a war, the second will also send a copy to our server.